# Installshield error 1628

Tags: zoo-tycoon-2

I am trying to install Zoo Tycoon 2 African Adventure. As the install starts, it all looks good, but when it gets to preparing installation, the progress bar stops about a third of the way in and I am given `Error 1628 Failed To Install`.

I have had this installed before, but I uninstalled it and now am trying to reinstall.

Any help?

I have tried the following:

1. Renaming Installshield folder
2. Clearing C:\Windows\Temp
3. Clean Boot
4. Stopping iDriver and msi services with task manager

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common error when trying to install older software(games especially) when using newer OSs.

Microsoft has posted a [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910816) about the issue with quite a few methods to fix it. Zoo Tycoon 2 African Adventure is even listed at the bottom as an affected property.

Comment: i have tried the KB on microsoft thats where i got the ideas for clean boot, renaming the installshield folder etc... thanks for your comment